# ASP.NET Identity + Entity Framework + SQLite to share

Tags: sqlite, entity-framework-6, c#-5.0, asp.net-identity-2, asp.net-mvc-5.2

For our project needs, I created my own ASP.NET Identity 2.0 Provider with SQLite database, and Entity Framework used in MVC 5.2 application. It's methods are all async. All of the problems with the connection to SQLite DB are resolved (I saw many questions regarding this)

So, my question is very simple:

Does it make sense to share my code with the community on GitHub? Can it be really helpful? What do you think?

Thanks for all answers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not exactly a technical question, but nevertheless: if I found something like this on GitHub I would totally look into it as I have developed similar features and it would definitely help me compare / improve my work.

Comment: So in your opinion it can be helpful?

Comment: That's what I said, right? :)

Comment: I think so :) OK, so I'll put that code into GitHub. Is SO a good place for sharing link on this? Or maybe there are some better places?

Answer (score 4):

So, OK. Here is the link on github where you can see and use if you need to my implementation of ASP.NET Identity 2.0 Membership with SQLite database, and Entity Framework OR/M. I'll also add some more info in readme file of repo about how to use/configure etc. your own implementation and how to skip all problems which can take place when you are working with SQLite and Entity Framework

https://github.com/darklektor/ASP.NET-Identity-SQLite-EntityFramework

Thanks for answers guys

Have a good and nice code :)

Comment: Ok, I added description and details about this custom implementation. You can read it in github readme.md of repo